# Alterar site via .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Tenho as seguintes urls:

```
www.meusite.com.br/pagina1
www.meusite.com.br/pagina1/a/b/c
www.meusite.com.br/pagina1/1/2/nome-perfil
```

Preciso que ao acessar meu site, eu tenha um redirecionamento em htaccess para um outro site, com a mesma base, tornando-se:

```
www.meunovosite.com.br/pagina1
www.meunovosite.com.br/pagina1/a/b/c
www.meunovosite.com.br/pagina1/1/2/nome-perfil
```

Como eu posso fazer isso?
Já tenho a seguinte configuração nele:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

E no index.php eu tenho:

```
header("Location: http://www.meunovosite.com.br");
```

Porém, se eu pesquisar meu site no Google, ele vai colocar as pastas que pertencem a ele, e neste caso, será redirecionado somente a home do site.

Comment: Você não pode configurar o seu servidor de aplicação para dar um 301 para o novo site? Acho que é o mais fácil.

Comment: O problema são as subpastas que são indexadas pelo google...

Comment: Você pode usar redirecionamento 301. Com isso todo o rank é passado pro novo link

Comment: Consegue postar um exemplo? Obg.

Comment: Da uma lida [aqui](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx) que ele fala do nginx, que foi o que eu já fiz, eu faço 301 de com.br para .com, ele da 301 em qualquer link com sub pasta ou não. (Não sou especialista nisso, mas acho que isso atenderia um cenário simples)

Answer (score 1):

Ficaria assim utilizando redirecionamento 301 via `htaccess`:

```
redirect 301 /pagina1 http://meunovosite.com.br/pagina1
redirect 301 /pagina1/a/b/c http://meusite.com.br/pagina1/a/b/c
redirect 301 /pagina1/1/2/nome-perfil http://meunovosite.com.br/pagina1/1/2/nome-perfil
```

[Ajuda](http://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/redirecionamento-301-em-php-asp-htaccess-coldfusion-e-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: Mas neste caso, eu uso um sistema roteando os links, então fica meio que impossível eu ajustar todos os links pertinentes ao site.. :(

Comment: Estava pensando que as URL's eram específicas(somente as 3 que postou).